# Data name in python conn.request

Tags: python, post, http-post, httprequest

When i make http request with html, I can tell the name of data (name="data").

```
<html>
<form action="http://192.168.1.100/urlhere" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="data"/>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

Is there any way to tell the name of data in python? Im doing the request like this, but I am not able to identify the name.

```
DATA=open("file.xml","rb")
HEADER= {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"}

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("192.168.1.100:80")
conn.request("POST", "/urlhere", DATA, HEADER)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the data you're sending in a dict:

```
...
conn.request("POST", "/urlhere", {'data': DATA}, HEADER)
...
```